# Finding the area of the black square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

[image]

The graph of $y=\sqrt{3}x$ and its inverse and the line $x=4$ is given.

I have restarted a course on functions and graphs. I managed to find the point of intersection between the green line and the blue line as $(4, \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}})$. I have been trying to find the other point on the blue line and till now I have only been able to estimate that it is ~$2.5$(picture is drawn to scale that's why) but that's probably an unreasonable approach as I am expected to give an exact value. How would one find the other end of the side of the black square on the blue line without its distance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let$$A=\left(a,\frac a{\sqrt3}\right)$$be an arbitrary point of the blue line and let$$B=\left(4,\frac 4{\sqrt3}\right).$$Then the straight line orthogonal to the blue line passing through $A$ is the line $y=-\sqrt3(x-a)+\frac a{\sqrt3}$. This line intersects the red line at$$C=\left(\frac{2a}3,\frac{2a}{\sqrt3}\right).$$What remains to be determined are the values of $a$ for which the distance from $A$ to $B$ is equal to the distance from $A$ to $C$. That happens when and only when $a=6\pm2\sqrt3$. See the picture below:

[image]

Numerically, the values of $a$ mentioned above are about $2.54$ and $9.46$.

Of course, if we add the assumption that the square is not cut by the red line, then the only valid solution is the one for which $a=6-2\sqrt3$, in which case the area of the square is equal to $\frac{32}3\left(2-\sqrt3\right)$.

Comment: I updated, the coordinate to $(4, \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}})$. I realised that this was wrong. Thanks for pointing this out. How did you get the second equation, the one in terms of $a$?

Comment: The square of the distance from $A$ to $B$ is $\frac43(a-4)^2$, whereas the square of the distance from $A$ to $C$ is $\frac49a^2$. So, the equation becomes$$\frac43(a-4)^2=\frac49a^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since the two lines are invers of each other and the slopes of them make $30°$ with the axis, the area of the square can be easily calculated by using Pythagoras.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the angle that $y = \sqrt3 x$ makes with the $x$-axis is $60º$, its inverse makes an angle of $30º$ so the angle between these two lines is $30º$. Also, $\sqrt{4^2 + (4/\sqrt3)^2} = 8/\sqrt{3}$, so we have:

[image]

and thus:

$$\frac{BC}{\sin 30º} = \frac{8/\sqrt3}{\sin 105º} \implies BC = \frac{4}{\sqrt3 \left( \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \cdot \frac{\sqrt3}{2} + \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \right)} =\frac{4}{\frac{3 \sqrt 2}{4} + \frac{\sqrt 6}{4}}$$
$$ = \frac{16}{3 \sqrt2 + \sqrt{6}}$$

Now as $BC = \sqrt{2}( \text{side length})$, the area of the square is $BC^2/2$ or just:

$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{256}{18 + 6 + 6 \sqrt{12}} = \frac{128}{24 + 12 \sqrt{3}} = \frac{32}{6 + 3 \sqrt3}.$$

Comment: A quicker method is $\sin^2(105º) = \sin^2 (75º) = \frac{1 - \cos(150º)}{2} = \frac{1 + \sqrt{3}/2}{2}$.